# Obtain the top-grossing product for each individual vendor

Tags: sql, sql-server

How do I obtain the top-grossing product for each individual vendor?

I came up with this so far and can't seem to proceed.

```
select vendor.Vendor_Name, Product.category AS Product
  , SUM(SalesFacts.Price * SalesFacts.Quantity) AS [Total Revenue]
FROM Vendor, Product, SalesFacts
WHERE SalesFacts.Vendor_Key = Vendor.Vendor_Key
AND SalesFacts.Product_Key = Product.Product_Key
GROUP BY vendor.Vendor_Name, product.Category
ORDER BY [Total Revenue] DESC;
```

[image: Vendor Table]

[image: Product Table]

[image: Sales Table]

(Product_Key and Vendor_Key are Foreign Key)

Comment: Evolve - move into the 21st century and stop using [old-style joins](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins).

Answer (score 0):

```
 select vendor.Vendor_Name,Product.category AS Product,
       MAX(SalesFacts.Price * SalesFacts.Quantity) OVER (PARTITION BY 
          SalesFacts.Vendor_Key,SalesFacts.Product_Key ORDER BY SalesFacts.Vendor_Key ) AS 
          [Total Revenue] FROM Vendor
      ,Product,SalesFacts WHERE SalesFacts.Vendor_Key = Vendor.Vendor_Key AND 
    SalesFacts.Product_Key = Product.Product_Key 
  --GROUP BY vendor.Vendor_Name,product.Category,SalesFacts.Price,SalesFacts.Quantity
   ORDER BY [Total Revenue] DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT 
        vendor.Vendor_Name, 
        Product.Category AS Product,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY vendor.Vendor_Name ORDER BY SUM(SalesFacts.Price * SalesFacts.Quantity)  DESC) RN
    FROM Vendor
        INNER JOIN SalesFacts ON SalesFacts.Vendor_Key = Vendor.Vendor_Key
        INNER JOIN Product ON SalesFacts.Product_Key = Product.Product_Key 
    GROUP BY vendor.Vendor_Name, product.Category   
) X
WHERE X.RN = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why a "category" should be a product.  More importantly, you should be fixing your query:

- *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.
- Use meaningful table aliases.

At the *product* level, this would be:

```
SELECT Vendor_Name, Product
FROM (SELECT v.Vendor_Name, p.Description AS Product,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.Vendor_Key ORDER BY SUM(sf.Price * sf.Quantity) DESC) as seqnum
      FROM SalesFacts sf JOIN
           Vendor v
           ON sf.Vendor_Key = v.Vendor_Key JOIN
           Product p
           ON sf.Product_Key = p.Product_Key 
      GROUP BY v.Vendor_Key, v.Vendor_Name, p.Product_Key, p.Description   
     ) vp
WHERE vp.seqnum = 1;
```

This can be easily modified to work for the category, but the question says "product" and the data has something that corresponds to that.