# Include the sales revenue amount into the select query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I also have a (somewhat) similar scenario as from [this guy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58461465/obtain-the-top-grossing-product-for-each-individual-vendor).
This is my current code:

```sql
SELECT Vendor_Name, Product
FROM (
    SELECT v.Vendor_Name, p.Description AS Product, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.Vendor_Key ORDER BY SUM(sf.Price * sf.Quantity) DESC) AS seqnum
    FROM SalesFacts sf JOIN Vendor v
    ON sf.Vendor_Key = v.Vendor_Key JOIN Product p
    ON sf.Product_Key = p.Product_Key 
    GROUP BY v.Vendor_Key, v.Vendor_Name, p.Product_Key, p.Description   
     ) vp
WHERE vp.seqnum = 1
```

The result of the query is show as below:
[image: TROLLED!]

1. What the above query did was to extract the top-grossing product for each vendor from the entire database, or in other words, the query obtained the highest-revenue product per vendor.
2. I wanted to add in a new column, which is **Sales Revenue**, which calculation can be derived as such:
   `price of item * quantity`. I wanted to add in the new column so that i can see see how much revenue the vendor earned from their respective best-selling products.

How do i obtain the same result with the inclusion of sales revenue column?

Comment: Is that code getting the highest-revenue product per vendor? Then you already calculate the revenue in order to decide that, so just add the same expression in the inner `select` list, then its alias in the outer one. Then use a CTE to avoid duplication there, and you could make that inner query a CTE too for IMO more logical flow of code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way your question is asked, you just want to return this column from the subquery so it can be accessed in the outer query:

```
SELECT Vendor_Name, Product, Sales_Revenue
FROM (
    SELECT 
        v.Vendor_Name, 
        p.Description AS Product, 
        SUM(sf.Price * sf.Quantity) Sales_Revenue
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY v.Vendor_Key ORDER BY SUM(sf.Price * sf.Quantity) DESC) AS seqnum
    FROM SalesFacts sf JOIN Vendor v
    ON sf.Vendor_Key = v.Vendor_Key JOIN Product p
    ON sf.Product_Key = p.Product_Key 
    GROUP BY v.Vendor_Key, v.Vendor_Name, p.Product_Key, p.Description   
     ) vp
WHERE vp.seqnum = 1
```

Comment: Never knew stack has this new thank you feature. But anyways thanks! Been stuck in this dilemma for quite a while. Also, i would like to apologize for the phrasing method of my question. Will try to improve the way i ask a question in future. Thank You!